# Grouping a databag by identical values in pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, apache-pig

I created the following Pig script to filter the sentences from a collection of web documents (Common Crawl) that mention a movie title (from a predefined data file of movie titles), apply sentiment analysis on those sentences and group those sentiments by movie.

```
register ../commoncrawl-examples/lib/*.jar; 
set mapred.task.timeout= 1000;
register ../commoncrawl-examples/dist/lib/commoncrawl-examples-1.0.1-HM.jar;
register ../dist/lib/movierankings-1.jar
register ../lib/piggybank.jar;
register ../lib/stanford-corenlp-full-2014-01-04/stanford-corenlp-3.3.1.jar;
register ../lib/stanford-corenlp-full-2014-01-04/stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar;
register ../lib/stanford-corenlp-full-2014-01-04/ejml-0.23.jar;
register ../lib/stanford-corenlp-full-2014-01-04/joda-time.jar;
register ../lib/stanford-corenlp-full-2014-01-04/jollyday.jar;
register ../lib/stanford-corenlp-full-2014-01-04/xom.jar;

DEFINE IsNotWord com.moviereviewsentimentrankings.IsNotWord;
DEFINE IsMovieDocument com.moviereviewsentimentrankings.IsMovieDocument;
DEFINE ToSentenceMoviePairs com.moviereviewsentimentrankings.ToSentenceMoviePairs;
DEFINE ToSentiment com.moviereviewsentimentrankings.ToSentiment;
DEFINE MoviesInDocument com.moviereviewsentimentrankings.MoviesInDocument;

DEFINE SequenceFileLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.SequenceFileLoader();

-- LOAD pages, movies and words
pages = LOAD '../data/textData-*' USING SequenceFileLoader as (url:chararray, content:chararray);
movies_fltr_grp = LOAD '../data/movie_fltr_grp_2/part-*' as (group: chararray,movies_fltr: {(movie: chararray)});

-- FILTER pages containing movie
movie_pages = FILTER pages BY IsMovieDocument(content, movies_fltr_grp.movies_fltr);

-- SPLIT pages containing movie in sentences and create movie-sentence pairs
movie_sentences = FOREACH movie_pages GENERATE flatten(ToSentenceMoviePairs(content, movies_fltr_grp.movies_fltr)) as (content:chararray, movie:chararray);

-- Calculate sentiment for each movie-sentence pair
movie_sentiment = FOREACH movie_sentences GENERATE flatten(ToSentiment(movie, content)) as (movie:chararray, sentiment:int);

-- GROUP movie-sentiment pairs by movie
movie_sentiment_grp_tups = GROUP movie_sentiment BY movie;

-- Reformat and print movie-sentiment pairs
movie_sentiment_grp = FOREACH movie_sentiment_grp_tups GENERATE group, movie_sentiment.sentiment AS sentiments:{(sentiment: int)};
describe movie_sentiment_grp;
```

Test runs on a small subset of the web crawl showed to be successfully give me pairs of a movie title with a databag of integers (from 1 to 5, representing very negative, negative, neutral, positive and very positive). As a last step I would like to transform this data into pairs movie title and a databag containing tuples with all distinct integers existing for this movie title and their count. The describe movie_sentiment_grp at the end of the script returns:

```
movie_sentiment_grp: {group: chararray,sentiments: {(sentiment: int)}}
```

So basically I probably need to FOREACH over each element of movie_sentiment_grp and GROUP the sentiments databag into groups of identical values and then use the COUNT() function to get the number of elements in each group. I was however not able to find anything on how to group a databag of integers into groups of identical values. Does anyone know how to do this?

Dummy solution:

```
movie_sentiment_grp_cnt = FOREACH movie_sentiment_grp{
    sentiments_grp = GROUP sentiments BY ?;
}
```

Comment: Just as a tip, you should try to limit the information in your question to only what is relevant to the problem.  Everything above the schema of `movie_sentiment_grp` is not important to the actual problem.  Having all that extra information clutters up an otherwise good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [CountEach](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/bags/CountEach.html) UDF from [Apache DataFu](http://datafu.org).  Given a bag it will produce a new bag of the distinct tuples, with the count appended to each corresponding tuple.

Example from the documentation should make this clear:

```
DEFINE CountEachFlatten datafu.pig.bags.CountEach('flatten');

-- input: 
-- ({(A),(A),(C),(B)})
input = LOAD 'input' AS (B: bag {T: tuple(alpha:CHARARRAY, numeric:INT)});

-- output_flatten: 
-- ({(A,2),(C,1),(B,1)})
output_flatten = FOREACH input GENERATE CountEachFlatten(B);
```

For your case:

```
DEFINE CountEachFlatten datafu.pig.bags.CountEach('flatten');

movie_sentiment_grp_cnt = FOREACH movie_sentiment_grp GENERATE
     group,
     CountEach(sentiments);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track.  `movie_sentiment_grp` is in the right format, and a nested `FOREACH` would be correct, except you can not use a `GROUP` in it.  The solution is to use a UDF.  Something like this:

**myudfs.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema('sentiments: {(sentiment:int, count:int)}')
def count_sentiments(BAG):
    res = {}
    for s in BAG:
        if s in res:
            res[s] += 1
        else:
            res[s] = 1
    return res.items()
```

This UDF is used like:

```
Register 'myudfs.py' using jython as myfuncs;

movie_sentiment_grp_cnt = FOREACH movie_sentiment_grp 
                          GENERATE group, myfuncs.count_sentiments(sentiments) ;
```